# How to purposefully delay the `account` PAM phase?

Tags: linux, ssh, pam

My OpenSSH server is getting bombarded with dictionary attacks on usernames, and instead of using `pam_tally2`, `fail2ban` or similar (or the frankly just ugly suggestion of "change the port" that keeps getting thrown around on various forums) to simply get rid of them, I want to mess with the attackers and waste their time (even if it's just their scripts' time, at least means *some* wasted CPU and port allocation they can't spend to attack others).

Therefore my idea is to introduce a delay of some sort in PAM's `account` phase (in the hopes of introducing the delay before OpenSSHd *can* even reply with "that user does not exist"), but the intuitive choice of the `pam_faildelay` module sadly only supports `auth`, which is never reached, because statistically almost all of the attacked "accounts" don't actually exist.

Also I'm not actually sure whether I want a *fail*delay, I think an unconditional delay *before* even checking the account would be even better here as to leak as little info as possible.

Given `pam_just_delay_right_here` is such an obvious thing to want, sounds like such an easy thing to implement (though I have no idea about PAM internals), and I wasn't able to find anything, I'm convinced I must just be searching for the wrong thing and would be glad for any help how to configure/implement this.

---

EDIT:

after implementing a `pam_exec /bin/sleep` solution as suggested by @roaima below, and testing further, it actually seems like my original "`account` instead of `auth`" idea was wrong: i actually *do* need `auth` because apparently that happens before `account`. just somehow `faildelay` never got triggered when I tried using that. my guess is either sshd detects "wrong user" early, or i was somehow misunderstanding the module stack, because that only ever worked with "correct user + wrong password". prepending an unconditional `pam_exec sleep` before the whole `auth` stack does however work fine (for PID-wasting values of "fine", but then again each login attempt spawns 3 sshd processes anyway so I don't care *that* much as to trust myself to write a safe PAM module instead)

Comment: `pam_exec` maybe? I've used it in the past but I can't off-hand remember whether it will get called at the point you want. I suspect it'll be too late in the process for you

Comment: Another thought would be to use `fail2ban` but instead of banning you redirect to a tarpit

Comment: @roaima technically that could work, but i'd prefer it to just always be slow, that way i can't leak info over the timing but most importantly i can't lock myself out. triggering your own fail2ban while you're trying to figure out what's going on with that DDOS attack isn't the greatest fun, been there done that.

Comment: @roaima `pam_exec` *does* seem to support all interfaces, it's just kinda painful to waste a perfectly fine PID for `sleep` there, but i'mma try :P

Comment: @roaima i can't believe it was this easy: `account   optional  pam_exec.so quiet /bin/sleep 5`. behaves exactly the same as before, except 5 seconds slower (and wasting a PID each time, but i guess there's worse... maybe i'll improve it some time by actually writing a module for this, but for now it works fine)

Comment: Fancy writing an answer to your question? You'll get a +1 from me for sure

Comment: @roaima i mean, you solved it though? :P

Comment: @nonchip OT but if you want to have an easy way to recover from fail2ban lockout, you could use `knockd` with a complex port sequence and `start_command   = fail2ban-client unban %IP%`